# Laravel - React has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: reactjs, laravel, apache, progressive-web-apps

I built an API with Laravel and uploaded it into the Linux sharing host and when I want to use API with my React SPA. It works perfectly but this time I uploaded my API Laravel source to a Centos server in a folder of my domain and when I want to connect to the API with my React SPA, Chrome says:

> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass >access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the >requested resource.

and when I add these codes to htaccess:

```
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

the error changes to:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not 
>   have HTTP ok status.

I have installed 
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors
in Laravel.

---

SPA domain: `web.example.com`
API domain: `example.com/test`

I tested it by changing the API domain to the main domain.

I activated `mod_header` in Centos.

---

```
// my kernel with laravel package
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'api' => [
            \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        ],
    ];
// my kernel with cors middleware that i created manually
protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
// my api route 
Route::namespace('Api')->middleware('cors')->group(function () {
```

Comment: have you added middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php

Comment: yes i add it to api section in middleware kernel, actually it's worked on my sharing host

Comment: Could you add a sample API call URL?

Comment: example.com/laravelapi/api/loign
example.com/laravelapi is main domain for api call

Comment: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status." — So what status does it have? Investigate why it has that. Then you'll know what you need to fix

Comment: @Quentin my request send to back via options and response is 405 method not allowed with cors error , i changed all api route to options but nothing happened same error

Answer (score 1):

I have this working in one of my projects: https://github.com/devinsays/laravel-react-bootstrap/search?q=cors&unscoped_q=cors.

In app/Http/Kernel.php:

`'cors' => \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,`

In the routes:

```
// Auth Endpoints
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'cors',
    'prefix' => 'api'
], function ($router) {
    Route::post('example', 'Auth\ExampleController');
});
```

And in cors/config.php:

```
<?php
return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Laravel CORS
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
    | to accept any value.
    |
    */
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['Content-Type', 'X-Requested-With'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
];
```

Hopefully this helps!